# Proportional distance to top in autolayout and device rotation

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout

I have an UIImageView in an iPAd Screen. The three Auto Constrains are 
1) centered horizontally in the container
2) fixed width 
3) fixed height

I have another constrain which tells the image view to be 100 points under the top of the screen.

If the device goes to landscape mode, I want to have this value 70 (the numbers 100 and 70 are imaginary, can be others, relations, proportions etc.)

What should I do for this without solving it programmatically, pure auto layout in the storyboard interface builder.

Thanks for helps.

Comment: Take a look at size classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the multiplier of a constraint, accessible by selecting the constraint in the XIB.

Comment: This helps to proportion of a single control to the container, but did not help (or I did not found how) me to change the distance to the top

Comment: It works when you center your image vertically in its container and use the multiplier on this constraint. Another option is to create an invisible view (view1) which has an equal height with multiplier 0.3 to another view (view2) which has the full height of the container. And link the imageview's top to view1's bottom. In this case the imageview should be positioned at .3 of the container's height. Please let me know if it's clear, otherwise I'll draw it out for you.